# How to set text in TextView being an item of GridView at event setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, gridview

I have custom TextView, and in GridView have 308 item TextView.

I want to set text when click item of GridView, I set text of TextView in event TextView setOnClickListener in function "getView" of "custom Adapter", it is work correctly.

But I want set text of TextView at event setOnItemClickListener in GridView, I tried a few way, but they all didn't work.

Code custom TextView:

```
package com.example.cocaro;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class CustomTextView extends androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int dai=getMeasuredWidth();
        setMeasuredDimension(dai,dai);
    }
}
```

Code custom Adapter:

```
package com.example.cocaro;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterGridViewCustom extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context myContext;
    int myLayout;
  //  ArrayList<String> arr;
    ArrayList<CustomTextView> arr;
    public AdapterGridViewCustom(Context myContext, int myLayout, ArrayList<CustomTextView> arr)
    {
        this.myContext = myContext;
        this.myLayout = myLayout;
        this.arr = arr;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return arr.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=inflater.inflate(myLayout,null);
        final CustomTextView customTextView=view.findViewById(R.id.custom_textview);
        customTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oo);
//        customTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View view) {
//                customTextView.setText("ok");
//            }
//        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Code main activity:

```
package com.example.cocaro;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gridBanCo;
    AdapterGridViewCustom adapterGridView;
    // ArrayList<String > list;
    ArrayList<CustomTextView > list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        addData();
        gridBanCo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                CustomTextView tv= (CustomTextView) gridBanCo.getItemAtPosition(position);//(CustomTextView) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
               tv.setText("okokoko");     //don't work
              //  adapterGridView.notifyDataSetChanged();
             //  ((TextView)view).setText("kkkkkkk");   //don't work
//                CustomTextView tv= (CustomTextView) view.findViewById((int)id);
//                tv.setText("okokoko");    //don't work
            }
        });
    }

    private void addData()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<308;i++)
            list.add(new CustomTextView(MainActivity.this));
        adapterGridView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void init() {
        gridBanCo=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridBanCo);
        list=new ArrayList<>();
        adapterGridView=new AdapterGridViewCustom(this,R.layout.o_caro,list);
        gridBanCo.setAdapter(adapterGridView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to solve my problem.

create class to contain these properties of TextView like text, textColor,.... And getView function of Adapter then set properties for TextView.

code class TextView contain these properties of TextView:

```
package com.example.cocaro;

public class clsTextView {
    private String textInTextView;
    private String textColorInTV;
    public clsTextView(String textInTextView, String textColorInTV) {
        this.textInTextView = textInTextView;
        this.textColorInTV = textColorInTV;
    }


    public clsTextView(String textInTextView) {
        this.textInTextView = textInTextView;
    }

    public String getTextInTextView() {
        return textInTextView;
    }

    public void setTextInTextView(String textInTextView) {
        this.textInTextView = textInTextView;
    }

    public String getTextColorInTV() {
        return textColorInTV;
    }

    public void setTextColorInTV(String textColorInTV) {
        this.textColorInTV = textColorInTV;
    }
}
```

code file custom Adapter:

```
package com.example.cocaro;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AdapterGridViewCustom extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context myContext;
    int myLayout;
  //  ArrayList<String> arr;
    ArrayList<clsTextView> arrTextView;
    public AdapterGridViewCustom(Context myContext, int myLayout, ArrayList<clsTextView> arrTextView)
    {
        this.myContext = myContext;
        this.myLayout = myLayout;
        this.arrTextView = arrTextView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrTextView.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return arrTextView.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

   boolean isX=true;

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) myContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view=inflater.inflate(myLayout,null);
        final CustomTextView customTextView=view.findViewById(R.id.custom_textview);
        customTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oo);
        customTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        customTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
        customTextView.setFocusable(false);
        customTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        clsTextView tv=arrTextView.get(i);
        customTextView.setText(tv.getTextInTextView());
        customTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(tv.getTextColorInTV()));

        return view;
    }
   
}
```

code main activity :

```
package com.example.cocaro;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    GridView gridBanCo;
    AdapterGridViewCustom adapterGridView;

    ArrayList<clsTextView > listTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        addData();

        gridBanCo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
               listTextView.set(i,new clsTextView("kkk","#00cc00"));//The command worked
               adapterGridView.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
    }

    private void addData()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<266;i++)
            listTextView.add(new clsTextView("","#ff0000"));
        adapterGridView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void init() {
 
        gridBanCo=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridBanCo);
        listTextView=new ArrayList<>();
        adapterGridView=new AdapterGridViewCustom(this,R.layout.o_caro,listTextView);
        gridBanCo.setAdapter(adapterGridView);
    }
}
```